# mongodb query findById() and month and year

Tags: mongodb

I've searched for an answer on how to solve my problem but found nothing, so I am very sorry if I am repeating a question that has been asked before.

i'm trying to find a results for a specific **userId** by **month** and **year**.
the dates has been stored in db in this format : **yyyy-mm-dd**.

I'm trying the following query with Mongo v3.6.8:

```
db.collection.find({
  $and: [
    {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          {
            $month: {
              $dateFromString: {
                dateString: "$Ntry.BookgDt",
                format: "%Y-%m-%d"
              }
            }
          },
          12
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          {
            $year: {
              $dateFromString: {
                dateString: "$Ntry.BookgDt",
                format: "%Y-%m-%d"
              }
            }
          },
          2020
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          "id",
          "5fab9a66c493dc4a3c49a7a3"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Sample data:

```
[
  {
    "userid": "5fab9a66c493dc4a3c49a7a3",
    "name": "user name",
    "acc": "admin",
    "Blas": "00.00",
    "Ntry": [
      {
        "Amt": "11.72",
        "BookgDt": "2020-08-16",
        
      },
      {
        "Amt": "16.72",
        "BookgDt": "2020-06-23",
        
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "userid": "5fab9a77c493dc4a3c49a7a3",
    "name": "user name",
    "acc": "user",
    "Blas": "00.00",
    "Ntry": [
      {
        "Amt": "11.72",
        "BookgDt": "2020-08-23",
        
      },
      {
        "Amt": "16.72",
        "BookgDt": "2020-07-23",
        
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

so my query is to find all **Ntry** for UserId **5fab9a66c493dc4a3c49a7a3** in month **8** and year **2020**, but I got this erorr:

*query failed: (ConversionFailure) $dateFromString requires that 'dateString' be a string, found: array with value ["2020-08-16", "2020-06-23"]*

can you please help me to find the suitable query, and thank you in advance.

[here is also a **mongo play ground** link, It's the best for quick editing:](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JCHs2jtMlcE)

Comment: by the way, I'm using nodjs with mongosse in the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pipeline should work:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
// Top level match                                                               
{$match: {userid: "5fab9a66c493dc4a3c49a7a3"}}

// Next, only keep entries in the Ntry array with month 8 and year 2020.          
// addFields: {"Ntry": {$filter: {input: "$Ntry"}}} means overwrite the          
// original Ntry array.                                                          
,{$addFields: {"Ntry": {$filter: {
                input: "$Ntry",
                as: "zz",
                cond: { $and: [
{$eq: [{$month:{$dateFromString:{dateString:"$$zz.BookgDt",format: "%Y-%m-%d"}}}\
, 8] },
{$eq: [{$year: {$dateFromString:{dateString:"$$zz.BookgDt",format: "%Y-%m-%d"}}}\
, 2020] }
                               ]}
            }}
    }}

// It is possible everything got filtered out of the Ntry array, leaving         
// an empty (size 0) array.  We likely do not want that, so further              
// cut down the output material.  You can comment this out to see what           
// changes, especially if you change the month and year targets above.           
,{$match: {$expr: {$ne: [ {$size: "$Ntry"}, 0] } }}

]);
```

It's probably simpler to call `$dateFromString` twice but if you are feeling adventurous, then use `$let` inside the `cond` to convert the date just once:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$match: {userid: "5fab9a66c493dc4a3c49a7a3"}}

,{$addFields: {"Ntry": {$filter: {
        input: "$Ntry",
        as: "zz",
        cond: {
           $let: {
                vars: {dd: {$dateFromString:{dateString:"$$zz.BookgDt",format: "%Y-%m-%d"}}},
                in: {
                    $and: [
                      {$eq: [{$month: "$$dd"}, 8] },
                      {$eq: [{$year:  "$$dd"}, 2020] }
                    ]
                }
           }
        }
    }}
}}
,{$match: {$expr: {$ne: [ {$size: "$Ntry"}, 0] } }}
]);
```